# How to change the page content without reloading

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I want to know how can I change the content of a div (for example: `<div id="MyDiv"></div>`) when I click any link for an HTML file with PHP code?

Now, I tried to do this:

```
$(function(){
    $("a").on("click", function () {
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        $("#MyDiv").load(href);
    });
});
```

But it replaces the content of the whole page.

Comment: xml http request

Comment: I've already answered my question

Comment: well then I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, I need to prevent the default action, this will do what I want:

```
$(function(){
    $("a").on("click", function () {
        event.preventDefault();
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        $("#MyDiv").load(href);
    });
});
```